# Set timeout function not slowing down

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a loading screen and have different sets of text show up while it's loading, but when I increase the rate to 5 secs, the function skips to the last set of loading screen text and doesn't show the other sets. How can I solve this issue?

JS:

```
const loadingDiv = document.getElementById('loading-text')

let intervalTimerId = setTimeout(function start() {
    console.log('start');
    intervalTimerId = setTimeout(start, 1000); // (*)

    loadingDiv.textContent = "Welcome To StudioPick." (start, 5000); 

    loadingDiv.textContent = "Loading studios..." (start, 5000);
    loadingDiv.textContent = "Almost done..." (start, 5000); 
    loadingDiv.textContent = "Let's get started" (start, 5000);

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        console.log('all contents loaded in the dom');
    });


    
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function () {
    show('page', true);
    show('loading', false);
});
```

Comment: I see that you changed time to 5 milliseconds, not seconds. Also, you set all timeouts at once to the same time

Comment: the time argument to setTimeout is in milliseconds - also, `document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0] !== undefined` is not how you wait for the DOM to be ready

Comment: So i can just get rid of it?

Comment: This is a sample code I found offline

Comment: Not sure if you can get rid of it - depends - is the *DOM Content Loaded* yet?

Comment: Yessir, it is .

Comment: unrelated: don't use `innerHTML` unless you're actually trying to convert raw HTML source code to page DOM elements. If you just want to set text, use `textContent` instead. Also, just capture `const loadingDiv = document.getElementById('loading-text')` at the top, so you don't need to constantly query the document for an element that's always going to be the same element anyway.

Comment: @Grmin you should be using promises for this. I think one issue is you are registering four setTimeout calls in a row. These will all wait for a total of 5ms(5000 would be 5 seconds). If you are trying to get the behavior of 5seconds for the first message, followed by 5 seconds for the second message etc for a total of 20seconds. You would either need to nest these setTimeout calls or use promises to get the chaining behavior.

Comment: I just updated my function above. Is this how I set it up? Sorry if it's wrong, i'm still learning JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues in your code.

1. We don't see where you are waiting for the dom loaded event, since we can't verify we need to ensure that you have guarded your dom accesses by the DOMContentLoaded event. If you missed this step then the updates would not happen.
2. The ordering of your setTimeouts based on reading it seems like you want one after another of these messages to display. As written in the question these would all effectivly run at the same time.

The best way to address this issue is use JS promises if available in your target browser (probably works unless you need IE compatibility and cannot load a polyfill).

A partial solution I made to use promises can be read below.

## Promises are the best approach for these chained events

`index.html`

```html
<div id="loading-text"></div>
```

`index.js`

```js
function timeout(ms) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
function loadingScreen() {
  var loadingText = document.getElementById('loading-text');
  loadingText.innerText = "Welcome To StudioPick."
  var delay = 1000;
  return timeout(delay)
    .then(() => { loadingText.innerText = "Loading studios..."; return timeout(delay) })
    .then(() => { loadingText.innerText = "Almost done..."; return timeout(delay) })
    .then(() => { loadingText.innerText = "Let's get started"; return timeout(delay) })
    .then(() => { loadingText.style.display = "none" })
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  loadingScreen();
});
```

If you were to paste these two into codepen.io or a similar site you will see that we iteratively step through each message.

The alternative to fix your setTimeout would to nest the setTimeout calls.

### Alternative for browser compatibility

```js
function loadingScreenWithNestedSetTimeout() {
  var loadingText = document.getElementById('loading-text');
  loadingText.innerText = "Welcome To StudioPick.";
  var delay = 1000;
  setTimeout(() => {
    loadingText.innerText = "Loading studios...";
    setTimeout(() => {
      loadingText.innerText = "Almost done...";
      setTimeout(() => {
        loadingText.innerText = "Let's get started";
        setTimeout(() => {
          loadingText.style.display = "none";
        }, delay);
      }, delay);
    }, delay);
  }, delay);
}
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  loadingScreenWithNestedSetTimeout();
});
```

Comment: This works, but it doesn't go to the next page. Does this mean that it isn't waiting for  the DOM event to load?

Comment: The first set of code you provided is the only js I have in my script.js file

Comment: I put this in the console log and it tells me that all the contents have loaded as well, but it just gets stuck at 'lets get started' and doesn't show the next set of content. console.log('all contents loaded in the dom');

Comment: @Grmln does it start at "Welcome To StudioPick" then step through each and end with "Let's get started" That should be the behavior. Depending on what you want to do after that. We can hide the element etc... But I can't provide too much guidance from here. SO is for specific questions and I think we addressed the main concern. I'll update my code once more with an example of how we hide the element.

Comment: yes. It startes at welcome... and ends at lets get started.

Comment: @Grmln please see my update again. Hope it's useful and good luck.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is wrong since you have defined 5miliseconds not 5 seconds. If you want 5 seconds then use `5000` instead of only `5`

Also don't check the ready state with setInterval and that function. Instead use

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  console.log('all contents loaded in the dom');
});
```

Read more here:- [DOMContentLoaded](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/DOMContentLoaded_event)

Comment: I've changed it, but now it doesn't show the loading text

Comment: The code you provided has a lot bug. First of all setTimeout() is an asynchronus function. Browsers will skip it to background and go to the DOM eventlistener and whenever DOM loads the loader will immediately be hidden regardless of showing all loader texts.  So, you'll have to rewrite the code by yourself understanding the exact need. I suppose you need a loader until the page loads and if the page loads faster then the loader texts' transition will be faster, if the page loads slow then the transition will be slower. If this is the case let me know. I will update the answer with new code.

Comment: The page is loading faster than the text, so I want to slow it down so that I can show each of the text transitions and then show the page

Comment: So, after seeing the updated code I think you might learn javascript first. You have a very bad knowledge about the basics of Javascript. Please learn from any good resource about the basic fundamentals (at least). Best wishes for your journey. Don't be hasty before learning the root